# Oracle: Efficient query over date interval

Tags: oracle, datetime, intervals

I have tables representing events with start and end time (stored as DATE, TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE format), e.g.

```
MY_TABLE:
DATA       START           END  
A      1/11/2012 10:00    1/11/2012 12:00
B      2/12/2012 08:00    2/12/2012 16:00
```

And it frequently happens to have queries on such tables over time intervals, e.g.

```
SELECT data
  FROM my_table
 WHERE start BETWEEN t1 AND t2; -- usually we either use start or end time for every row.
```

Where t1 and t2 are DATE/TIMESTAMP values s.t. t1<= t2.

Since these queries are goin to be run on large tables, is there a better, that is, more effcient, way of performing queries like above?

Currently I don't know if any table with the structure above has a index on either of time-data columns, still it would be hardly a problem to add them. They have indexes on other non-time related columns.

I remember to have read somewehre that using analytic functions (like partition) these kind of query could be made much more efficient than simply using BETWEEN..AND. Unfortunately I can't find the link anymore and I don't know analytics functions, of which I have read just a few short introductions here and there on the net.

Since I have little time to investigate I'd like to ask you if you could confirm my theory and if you could lead me to an example related to my problem.

It goes without saying that I'm not asking you a quick answer to my problem, something to copy&paste, just a hint to understand if I'm looking in the right direction.

TIA

**EDIT:**
@jonearles : For the first statement I'd agree, but I'd like to know if the use of analytics functions isn't **actually** able to provide a more efficient query.

For the latter, yes I meant PARTITION BY clause. It occurs to me that is a silly specification, since analytical functions are expected to be used with a PARTITION BY clause. 
I apologyze for the confusion, as I said before I haven't looked much into the subject.

Comment: Answer added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is probably fine.  The simplest way to write a predicate is usually the best.  That's what Oracle expects, and is most likely what Oracle is optimized for.

You probably want to look into creating objects to improve the access methods.  Specifically [indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#i2062403) (if you're selecting a small amount of data) and [partitions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/toc.htm) (if you're selecting a large amount of data).

"Partition" can mean at least three different things in Oracle.  Perhaps you've confused the "partition by" clause in analytic functions with partitioning?